# Tracking multiple QR tags from a distance using webcam and Java

Tags: java, webcam, augmented-reality, zxing

I'm currently trying to build an application in Java, which should be able to read QR tags from a couple of meters.

At the moment, I have JavaCV running, for capturing frames from my iSight on my MBP. 
The problem is that it only supports a resolution of 640x480, which does not seem enough for [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) to recognizing the QR tags. 
I have been looking at a Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000, but I'm not entirely convinced, from my search, that it supports a high enough resolution for my project.

The application need to be platform agnostic, at least regarding OS X, Windows and Linux, which is the reason I'm doing it in Java.

My questions are:
Will the QucikCam pro record frames in 1080p as promised using the UVC drivers?
Is there a better camera?
Should I look at another framework than JavaCV and/or ZXing?
-Which?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution is not the issue; it decodes 320x240 regions on phones, as Barcode Scanner, easily. QR codes are especially simple to read. However if your QR code is in a tiny region of that 640x480 capture, like 50x30, yeah that's not going to be enough to decode reliably. I don't think any software could help you there.

I'd look at zooming in if you can.

Otherwise, I think you have some other issue; maybe the image data is in the wrong format somewhere